# Как выполнить команду привязанную к контролу не из этого контрола?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть некий пользовательский контрол. И есть у него команды. Так вот я хочу сделать отдельно от этого контрола кнопочку, которая бы выполняла команду, которая есть в этом контроле (она добавлена в `CommandBindings` этого контрола), но команда получается неактивна. Даже в процедуру `CanExecute` не заходит программа. Пытаюсь делать так

```
<local:SlideListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lbNot">
    <ListBoxItem Content="qwe"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="asd"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="zxc"/>
</local:SlideListBox>
<Button Command="{Binding GoNextCommand, ElementName=lbNot}"/>
```

Comment: Ваш код привязывается к свойству GoNextCommand у SlideListBox. Есть у него такое свойство?

Comment: @VladD, Да, есть.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в регистрации команды. Команда регистрируется в конструкторе класса SlideListBox. Было так

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(GetType(), goNextCommand);
```

Сделал так

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), goNextCommand);
```

Теперь все норм )

**PS**

`goNextCommand` в данном случае это не сама команда, а экземпляр `CommandBinding`, созданный на основе команды.